# Transpose matrix dual map

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

How do I see that the representing matrix of the dual map $f^*$ between finite-dimensional dual spaces is given by the transpose of the representing matrix of $f$? Here I want to assume that the matrix $f^*$ is represented with respect to the dual basis.

Apparently this result is very well-known, but I would like to see proof of this.

Comment: Just try to write in coordinates.

Comment: Here is a good reference: http://www.math.brown.edu/tgoodwil/dual.pdf

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Let $f: V \to \bar V$ be a linear transformation represented by the matrix $A = [a^i_j]$ relative to the basis $e_1,\dots,e_n$ for $V$ and $\bar e_1, \dots, \bar e_m$ for $\bar V$.  Let $\alpha^1, \dots, \alpha^n$ and $\bar \alpha^1, \dots, \bar \alpha^m$ denote the respective corresponding dual bases.

Suppose that $f^*:\bar V^* \to V^*$ satisfies $f^*(\bar \alpha^i) = \sum_{j} b^i_j \alpha^j$.  That is, suppose that $[b^i_j]^T$ is the matrix of $f^*$ relative to the dual bases.  It follows that for each $i,j$, we have
\begin{align*}
b^i_j & =
\sum_{k} b^i_k \delta^k_j = 
\sum_{k} b^i_k \alpha^k e_j = 
\left(\sum_{k} b^i_k \alpha^k\right) e_j =
f^*(\bar \alpha^i) e_j = 
(f^* \circ \bar \alpha^i) e_j
\\ & =
(\bar \alpha^i \circ f)(e_j) = 
\bar \alpha^i(f(e_j)) = 
\bar \alpha^i\left(\sum_{k}a^k_j \bar e_k\right) = 
\sum_{k}a^k_j \bar \alpha^i \bar e_k = 
\sum_{k}a^k_j \delta^i_k = a^i_j
\end{align*}
as desired.  That is, the matrix of $f^*$ with respect to the dual bases is $[b^i_j]^T = [a^i_j]^T = A^T$.

Comment: Are there any adjustments to be made when $V$ is a complex vector space?

Comment: @Roland well for one, the bars become a bit confusing. More seriously, this proof only works if you consider the application $\langle \alpha, e \rangle$ to be bilinear.  It is more common to consider this application to be [*sesquilinear*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sesquilinear_form), which is to say antilinear with respect to its argument from the dual space.

Comment: You took the matrix of dual space as bij transpose. Suppose we wont take the transpose, then what complications will come?

Comment: @AvinashBhawnani The only difference is that instead of ending by stating that $B = A$, I would end by stating that $B^T = A$.

Comment: To anyone who ends up here, I present an equivalent computation (more cleanly, in my opinion) [over here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4574493/81360).