# Matrix Representation of a Dual Map

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, linear-transformations

I am currently trying to prove that the matrix representation of a dual map ($S^*$) is the transpose of the matrix representation of the linear transformation $S$. I have seen a proof online but it was a little difficult for me to follow.

So far, I have the following:

Let $V$ and $W$ be vector spaces with ordered bases $\beta = \{\mathbb{v}_1, \mathbb{v}_2, \dots, \mathbb{v}_n\}$ and $\gamma = \{\mathbb{w}_1, \mathbb{w}_2, \dots, \mathbb{w}_m\}$ respectively. Let the respective dual space bases be denoted $\beta^* = \{\phi_1, \phi_2, \dots, \phi_n\}$ and $\gamma^* = \{\varphi_1, \varphi_2, \dots, \varphi_m\}$. Additionally, consider $S \in \mathcal{L}(V,W)$. I want to show:
$$[S]_\beta^\gamma = [S^*]_{\gamma^*}^{\beta^*}$$
where S is represented by $[S]_\beta^\gamma = (a_{ij})$.

At this point, I am lost as where to go. I think the next step might be to work with the matrix representation $[S^*]_{\gamma^*}^{\beta^*}$?

Any hints as to what approach I should take would be appreciated.

Comment: I answered this question [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1138700/81360).  Is that proof also difficult to follow?

Comment: I am particularly confused about the appearance of $\delta$. Not sure where that comes from but maybe I just need more coffee.

Comment: Or donuts, perhaps.  In any case: $\delta_{ij}$ (or $\delta^i_j$, as I wrote it) is the "Dirac delta", defined by
$$
\delta_{ij} = \begin{cases} 1 & i=j\\ 0 & i \neq j \end{cases}
$$
If it helps, you could just skip the step with the $\delta$ and simply note that when we write that first line, we're really adding a bunch of $0$-terms.

Comment: Oh okay, I am aware of that but had not seen the $\delta$ notation before. I'll take another look at your proof, thanks!

Comment: @amd "Let the respective dual bases be denoted..."