# $\det(T)=\det(T^*)$

Tags: linear-algebra, determinant, dual-spaces

I'm a little stuck with this exercise, it is a true or false question. Let V be a finite vectorial space under a field $\mathbb{F}$ and let $T: V \to V$ be a linear operator, then $\det(T)=\det(T^*)$ where $T^*$ is the dual of T.

I think this is a true statement but I do not know how to prove it.

Any suggestion?

Comment: Hint: If $A$ is a square matrix, the determinant of the tranpose of $A$ is the same as the one of $A$.

Comment: so basically I have to prove that $det[T]=det[T^*]^t$, but  $[T]=[T^*]^t$?

Comment: Indeed, if $\beta = (e_1,\dots,e_n)$ is an (ordered) basis for $V$, then for each $i$ you can define a linear map $e_i^* : V \to \mathbb F$ by $e_i^*(e_i) = 1$ and $e_i^*(e_j) = 0$ if $j \neq i$. In this case $\beta^* = (e_1^*,\dots,e_n^*)$ is an (ordered) basis for $V^*$, and $[T^*]_{\beta^*} = ([T]_\beta)^t$, as you can check.

Comment: @Bayesianguy See [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1138462/81360) for a proof of the fact that $[T^*] = [T]^t$.

Comment: Thanks, finally I could make sense of this exercise